# How to force Karma to reload http served javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, karma-runner

I came across this interesting article (http://danott.co/posts/rails-javascript-testing-using-karma.html) from @danott about **Rails Javascript Testing Using Karma**.

I tested it myself with the latest version of karma but I experience one problem:

If I set singleRun = false in the karma configuration, it does not reload the application.js file which is served from the local running instance of the Rails application.

```
files: [
    'http://myapp.dev/assets/application.js',
    ...
]
```

I would love to have the tests be run automatically every time some code gets changed and not to set it to singleRun and trigger the tests on my own. Can I somehow tell karma to reload the application.js file, before it executes a new round of tests?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Rail's stack, you should set up a file pattern that watches your assets folder, but not does not include or serve those files into your tests.

```
// spec/karma/config/unit.js
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'http://rails.dev/assets/application.js',
  'spec/javascripts/*.js',
  { pattern: 'app/assets/javascripts/*.js', // <-- this is the bit that's important
    watched: true,
    included: false,
    served: false }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Having Karma fetch the `application.js` over HTTP forces you to have the dev environment running and applying a watch pattern like @danott suggests.

If you use a rake task which makes Karma aware of Sprockets by injecting all the files required in your `application.js`, you don't have this constraint.

In my rake task I have this:

```
sprockets = Rails.application.assets
sprockets.append_path Rails.root.join("spec/karma")
files = Rails.application.assets.find_asset("application_spec.js").to_a.map {|e| e.pathname.to_s }
```

along with my karma configuration file:

```
files: [
  APPLICATION_SPEC,
  'app/assets/javascripts/angular/*/*.{coffee,js}',
  'spec/javascripts/**/*_spec.{coffee,js}'
]
```

where I replace `APPLICATION_SPEC` with all the sprocket `files`. I wrote a [tutorial](http://sebastien.saunier.me/blog/2014/02/04/angular--rails-with-no-fuss.html) if you want the big picture.